# how to use jquery file upload plugin in django framework with python

Tags: jquery, python, django, file-upload, multifile-uploader

i'm new in jquery field and i want to use jquery file upload plugin in my web site like what that's been described in this demo:
[jquery File Upload Demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)
i don't know how to use it in django framework with python programming language
can anyone please help
i'v added plugin and i have used it in the template but before everything else the page looks like this:
[problem](http://up.vatandownload.com/images2/5x8vqq4swew6wnau1whx.png)

i don't know how to fix this bug, the browse button should not be here and there shouldn't be an input line
plus, this allows user to just upload one file
i'm really puzzled
there are a lot of documents in the internet but they didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure it would help, but just the other day I made a [sample django project](https://github.com/yaniv-aknin/django-s3upload) that utilizes jQuery File Upload and Amazon S3's new CORS support to upload files directly to S3 in a django project.

Perhaps that code sample (and accompanying `README`...) could be relevant to you.

Comment: can you help me with your code, i can't understand it so much and also i can't run it, i use pycharm as my IDE and it doesn't recognize settings, i'd like to get some help if it's possible :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with pycharm, but perhaps I could help. Fee free to contact me through [here](http://yaniv.aknin.name/) and I'll see what I can do.